# How to change DropDownList Selected value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to change the selected value in javascript and get the selected value in codebehind page? AutoPostBack is set to false.

Answer (score 28):

You can change it like this:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl-id');
var opts = ddl.options.length;
for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
    if (ddl.options[i].value == "some-value"){
        ddl.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but when your page gets postback the value will be changed to which was set by the pageload. then what to do???

Answer (score 15):

```
//setting the value of a drop down list
document.getElementById('my_drop_down').selectedIndex=2;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'code behind page'.

But this is the way to get the selected value of a dropdown list:
document.getElementById('dropdown').value

Comment: To add to Avi Y's comment, selectedIndex of 2 is the 3rd item in the list, since the index starts at 0. Also, setting the index to -1, clears the dropdown of any text.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,of%20the%20first%20option%20selected.