# Javascript control flow, accessing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a Calendar with Javascript.  The problem is that when the the buildCalendar() method will repeat its values on Sunday and Monday.  Here is the HTML and Javascript Code

```
function setDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDate();
    document.getElementById("myDay").value = day;
    document.getElementById("myMonth").value = month;
    document.getElementById("myYear").value = year;
}

function buildCalendar() {
    var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("myYear").value, document.getElementById("myMonth").value, 1);
    var weekDay = firstDate.getDay();
    var theDate = firstDate.getDate();
    var theMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
    var theYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
    var newDay = new Date(theYear, theMonth + 1, 1);
    var lastDate = new Date(newDay - 1);
    var lastDay = lastDate.getDate();
    document.write("<table class='caltable' border='1'><tr><th>");
    document.write("<tr><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th>");
    document.write("</th></tr>");
    var col = 0;
    for (var i = theDate - weekDay; i <= lastDay; i++) {
        if (col == 0) {
            document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>");
            col++;
        }
        if (col == 6) {
            document.write("<td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
            col = 0;
        } else {
            document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            col++;
        }
    }  
    document.write("</table>");
}

function getMonthName() {
    var e = getElementById("myMonth").selectedIndex;
    var monthName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    return monthName;
}
```

The HTML code is just a bunch of divs that hold the calender and the current month, date, and day.  How would I add the month as a header in the table created by Javascript?  More specifically, how could I access the options values in the select tag?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./CSS/calendar.css"> 
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "./Calendar/task.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad = "setDate(); buildCalendar();">
        <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "left">  Left Div   </div>
        <div id = "right"> Right Div </div>
        <div id = "bottomLeft"> Shows calendar </div>
        <div id = "topLeft"> Day:<input id = "myDay" type="number" min = "1" max = "31">Month:<select id = "myMonth"><option value = "0">January</option> <option value = "1">February</option><option value = "2">March</option><option value = "3">April</option><option value = "4">May</option><option value = "5">June</option><option value = "6">July<option value = "7">August</option><option value = "8">September</option><option value = "9">October</option><option value = "10">November</option><option value = "11">December</option></select> Year:<input id = "myYear" type = "number" min = "100"> TopLeft Div shows form components for date  </div>
        <div id = "topRight"> Shows the form to add task </div>
        <div id = "bottomRight"> Show list of tasks </div>
            </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to dynamically change the selected value of a drop down menu with JavaScript? If yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029276/how-to-change-dropdownlist-selected-value-in-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript

Comment: Awesome.  That is helpful.  The main issue is that the Sundays and Mondays are repeated when the code is run and the table is created.  It shows the 7th as being on Sunday and Monday for example.